# magento uncheck same as billing in checkout

Tags: onepage-checkout

I would like to uncheck all shipping methods. When a customer is on a checkout page, radio button is not preselected (all circles are empty).

I use now a onepage extension: http://store.lotusbreath.com/magento-extension/lotusbreath-one-step-checkout.html

I already tried to contact them, but they dont give a reaction. It should not that hard, just uncheck it.. But searching for 2 days now :(

Regards..